# Returning to page that brought you there Django

Tags: python, django, formview

In Python/Django I have a FormView that allows you to add certain field choices ad hoc.

> (Example: Selecting a soda from the soda dropdown)
>
> Select Favorite soda: [_Soda_Choices_Dropdown_] +Add soda

I want to be able to add a soda on the fly, and when I save the soda I want the success URL to be the page that brought you there.

**[Page 1] --> [Create new soda FormView] --Success-> [Page 1]**

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:**

It would be better to **use `next` parameter** in the request to redirect to the page that bought us to form page instead of using `HTTP_REFERER`.

Lets say you are on page `some_page.html` having a link to the `MySodaFormView` page. Here, pass the `request.path` as a `next` parameter. This will be used when redirecting.

```
<a href='/my/soda/form/page/?next={{request.path}}'>Create new soda</a>
```

Then in `MySodaFormView` when rendering the page, pass the `next` parameter in the context. This parameter will be passed in `form` action and will be used when redirecting.

In your soda formview template, specify `next` parameter in the form `action`.

```
<form method="POST" action="/my/soda/form/page/?next={{next_url}}">
```

Your view would look something like:

```
class MySodaFormView(FormView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MySodaFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['next_url'] = self.request.GET.get('next') # pass `next` parameter received from previous page to the context 
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        next_url = self.request.GET.get('next')
        if next_url:
            return next_url # return next url for redirection
        return other_url # return some other url if next parameter not present
```

**EDIT: The below approach using `HTTP_REFERER` might not work sometimes as some browsers have passing referer feature turned off or provide the user an option to disable that feature.**

To return to the page that bought you there, you can use `HTTP_REFERER` header present in the [`HttpRequest.META`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) dictionary.

`HttpRequest.META` is a standard Python dictionary containing all available HTTP headers. One of the headers among them is `HTTP_REFERER` which contains the referring page if any.

Since you are using `FormView`, you can override the `get_success_url()` function to redirect on success to the page which bought the user to `MySodaFormView`. We will get this page using the value of `HTTP_REFERER` in the `request.META` dictionary.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class MySodaFormView(FormView):

    def get_success_url(self):
        referer_url = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') # get the referer url from request's 'META' dictionary
        if referer_url:
            return referer_url # return referer url for redirection
        return other_url # return some other url if referer url not present
```

**Note:** Using `HTTP_REFERER` from `request.META` dictionary may not be a "best practice" as some browsers have passing referer feature turned off or provide the user an option to disable that feature. In that case, your redirection would not work properly. You could instead pass a `?next=` parameter in the url and in your `get_success_url()` function, use the value of `next` to get the url to redirect to.

Comment: Please elaborate. `Page 1` is not a fixed page. User can reach the `MySodaFormView` page from multiple pages i guess according to the question.

Comment: Are you referring to this case where a user arrives at a form, fills in the information and then submits. The `HTTP_REFERER` is then the form page's URL, and not the URL of the page the user came from in the first place

Answer (score 0):

```
def soda_view(request):
   # your code goes here

   url = "{0}/{1}".format(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'), args)

   return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Comment: Generally, answers without explanations are considered to be relatively useless to future viewers. Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

FormView, along with other generic class-based views that have FormMixin, has a method `get_success_url()` that you can use to return to the same page. It would look something like this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('url_name_of_page_1')
```

Or, to combine this with Geo Jacob's answer, get the referring URL out of the HTTP headers:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    if 'HTTP_REFERER' in request.META:
        return request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
    else:
        # Do something with the error case
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `FormView`, simply do this:

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse

class YourView(FormView):
    success_url = reverse('first-page')
```

In your `urls.py`:

```
url(r'/foo/bar/', some.view, name='first-page'),
```

`first-page` being the name of the view that renders `Page 1` in your diagram.