# How to return to a filtered page using a Class Based UpdateView in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to create a Django admin like interface where a user can directly enter data through a model form but not through the admin interface. The Django admin interface returns to a list page or a filtered list page (based on where from admin started editing). While I can redirect the success url to the "all-queryset" list page, I could not figure out how to redirect the success url to a "filtered" list page.

Following the answer here: [Returning to page that brought you there Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766235/returning-to-page-that-brought-you-there-django) this is my code so far:

```
class MyModelUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
     template_name = 'catalog/mymodel_change.html'
     form_class = MyModelForm
     queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
     filter_class = MyModelListFilter    

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(MyModelUpdateView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['return_url'] = self.request.GET.get('return')
       return context

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return self.success_message % dict(
           cleaned_data,
           display_name=self.object.display_name,
           id=self.object.pk)

    def get_success_url(self):
       return_url = self.request.GET.get('return')
       if return_url:
            return return_url 
       return 'home/mymodellist/'
```

My form html

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="{{ request.path }}">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

I have also tried `request.path_info`.

The success url redirects to the list view page , `e.g., home/mymodellist/,` but I want to return `home/mymodel/?fliterlist='search-term'` if the user start editing from a filtered list page. I have tried `HttpRequest.META` as well as suggested in the above link, but essentially I got the same results.

In the Django admin interface the update-view url goes to `home/mymodellist/<int:pk>/change/` when the editing starts from  "all-queryset" list page, whereas the same url goes to `home/mymodellist/<int:pk>/change/?_changelist_filters='search-term'`. How can I do that? Using Django 2.0.

I appreciate any pointers, directions or suggestions. Thank you so much.

Comment: Since the `return` hidden input is in your form, it will be in the POST data, not GET.

Comment: Changing to POST redirects to {{ home/mymodellist/<int:pk>/change/ }} while I want it to go either to  {{ home/mymodellist/ }} or {{ home/mymodel/?fliterlist='search-term' }} based on my initial referring page.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If you do `return_url = self.request.POST.get('return')` and then `print(return)` what does it say in the console?

Comment: It says /home/mymodellist/544/change/. I kind of understand it because this is the path of the updateview form. This is where the path was requested through {{ request.path }}. I have to get the link to the previous page, i.e. /home/mymodellist/?q='some-text'/

Comment: I kind of solved it by using value = "{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERRER }}" in my form input because that gives the previous url.