# Returning to page that brought you there Django - double deep

Tags: python, django

For my Python/Djang app I would like to have button 'back' on every page level, that should take you the page you came from.

My structure:

```
Main webpage
-> All patients list -> View patients credentials -> Edit patients data
-> Dentists patients list -> View patients credentials -> Edit patients data
-> Orthopedy patients list -> View patients credentials -> Edit patients data
```

First issue was, that "View patients credentials", could be accessed from different pages.
I went pass that with help from Rahul Gupta [Returning to page that brought you there Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766235/returning-to-page-that-brought-you-there-django), with solution using url:

```
'?next={{request.path}}'
```

Problem occurs when I would like to use
the same solution to go back 2 times from "Edit patients data", through "View patients credentials"
to web that brought you there.
Is there any better way to deal with that issue, than to add with every step new 'next' address: ie. '?next1=XX?next2=YY?next3=ZZ' etc?
With two steps this solution would be fine, but would very problematic if I had much more steps, or if
I require button to work like 'back button' in webpage, leading you for, let's say, 10 or more last pages.

My code:
In "All patients list", "Dentists' patients list", "Orthopedy patients list" I use:

```py
{% for patient in patient_list %}
    <a href='{% url 'patients:patientscredentials' pk=patient.pk %}?next={{request.path}}'>
        {{ patient }}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

In my PatientsCredentialsView I use:

```py
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['next_url'] = self.request.GET.get('next') 
        return context
```

In my 'patients_credentials.html' I use:

```py
<a class='btn btn-primary' href={{  next_url }}>Back</a>
```

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: You can just simply use javascript and `window.history.back();`, no need to do much with django

Answer (score 0):

You can access the referrer page with `{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}` like this:

```py
<a class='btn btn-primary' href={{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}>Back</a>
```